# Problema em fazer import do models User

Tags: python, django

Estou fazendo alguns testes em um projeto Django. Criei um módulo bem simples só para testes mesmo. Segue abaixo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def teste():
    for i in User.objects.all():
        print i.username

if __name__ == "__main__":
    teste()
```

Ao executar o código, esse erro é retornado:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "teste.py", line 6, in 
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django   /contrib/auth/**init**.py", line 6, in 
> from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django  /middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in 
> from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in 
> from django.core.cache import get_cache
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/**init**.py", line 69, in 
> if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 54, in **getattr**
> self._setup(name)
> File "/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 47, in _setup
> % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but   settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

OBS.: Dentro do `python manage.py shell` com o comando %run teste.py, o código funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Esta não é a forma "comum" de executar um projeto com Django, mas se você quer apenas resolver o problema em questão, a solução está em definir a variável `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Quando você roda o comando pelo `python manage.py shell`, esta variável é definida automaticamente, o que faz com que neste caso não ocorra o erro.

Para definir a variável manualmente, você pode colocar o seguinte código no começo do seu script:

```
import os
# estou considerando que o nome do projeto (e não o app!) seja "helpdesk"
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'helpdesk.settings'
```

Outra opção é definir a variável no seu shell em vez do código. Assim:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=helpdesk.settings
```

Em todo caso, recomendo que você não faça dessa forma. É mais simples e confiável usar o `manage.py`, ou então fazer um código "tradicional", usando modelos, views e templates.

Comment: Agora esta retornando : ImportError: Could not import settings 'help.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named help.settings

Comment: meu path /home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/help/
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib/python27.zip
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib64/python2.7
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib64/python2.7
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7 
...

Comment: meu wsgi : 
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/carlos/myworkspace/helpdesk/help')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "help.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: "help" é o nome do app ou do projeto? Já tentou com "helpdesk.settings" em vez de "help.settings"? Outra opção é você definir o DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE como uma variável de ambiente, assim: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="help.settings"`

Comment: "help" é o nome do app e "helpdesk" é do projeto. O arquivo settings esta na pasta "help". $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE e $PYTHONPATH estão certos. Estou já dois dias pesquisando e testando e nada. Vou continuar e qualquer coisa posto. Obrigado Michael.

Comment: Ok. Certifique-se apenas de usar "helpdesk.settings" então. O correto é sempre usar o nome do site/projeto, e não do app.

Comment: Se o app é "help", o arquivo `settings.py` não deveria estar na pasta `help` mas na pasta `helpdesk` (a pasta do projeto, junto com o `urls.py` mestre e o `wsgi.py`) (o settings é do site inteiro, não do app e assim `helpdesk.settings` funcionaria)